# Calculating Numerator and Denominator using VBA macro

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am having problems with calculating numerator and denominator with excel VBA. The num and den are limited to the quarter in which data was entered in the excel spreadsheet.

Here is an example:
I have two columns in my excel sheet:

```
Date_data_entered_for each_person   Number of visits to the office
1/1/2009                                            5
1/10/2009                                           6
2/10/2009                                           7
5/12/2009                                           9
```

Based on this example, I have to calculate "average number of visits" per quarter = sum of visits/number of persons. In this example for first quarter of 2009, the data was entered for 3 persons and the total number of visits were, 5+6+7 = 18, hence the average = 18/3 = 6.

The code I have written is:

```
Function Visits(target_timeframe)

    Target_Quarter = Format(target_timeframe, "YYYYq")

    For vRow = 2 To 2000

        entered_timeframe = Format(Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & vRow).Value, "YYYYq")

        Entered_Visits = Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & vRow).Value 'equals value of column

        If (entered_timeframe = Target_Quarter) Then
            denominator = denominator + 1
            If (Entered_Visits > 0) Then
                numerator = numerator + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If denominator > 0 Then
        Average = numerator / denominator
    Else
        Average = "N/A"
    End If

End Function
```

I am not able to figure out what is wrong with code. Its not calculating the average. I would be extremely grateful if somebody could help me with this issue.

Thanks for you time!

Comment: For future reference, you should specify what exactly isn't working.  For example, what's wrong with the average returned?  Is it always 1?  Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that instead of:

```
numerator = numerator + 1
```

You want:

```
numerator = numerator + Entered_Visits
```

With the current code, you're simply adding 1 to the numerator each time, when in reality you want to be adding the number of visits to the numerator.